# Why is object copied?

Tags: c#, reflection, copy

Consider the following code:

```
class ObjectAccessor {
  ...
  static public void SetValueAtPath(ref object obj, List<PathEntry> path, 
                                    object value)
  {
    if (path.Count == 0)
      obj = value;

    object container = obj;
    for (int i = 0; i < path.Count - 1; i++)
      container = GetMember(container, path[i]);
    SetMember(container, path[path.Count - 1], value);
  }
  ...
}
```

When calling `SetValueAtPath` I intend to assign `value` to a specific field or property deep inside `obj` that is found by following the `path`. I expect the `container` variable to point to the actual object that contains the field and `SetMember` to modify that field. Since container is a reference, original `obj` should be also modified. However, according to the debugger, only `container` is modified and `obj` remains unchanged. Where and why the copy is created?

Here are the definitions of the types and functions used in the code above:

```
class PathEntry
{
  public enum PathEntryKind
  {
    Index,
    Name
  }
  public PathEntryKind Kind;
  public int Index;    // Kind == Index
  public string Name;  // Kind == Name
}

class ObjectAccessor {
  ...
  static public object GetMember(object obj, PathEntry member) 
  {
    if (member.Kind == PathEntry.PathEntryKind.Index)
      return ((IList)obj)[member.Index];
    else
      return GetFieldOrPropertyValue(obj, member.Name);
  }

  static public object GetFieldOrPropertyValue(object obj, string name)
  {
    FieldInfo fieldInfo = obj.GetType().GetField(name, BindingFlags.Public |
      BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance);
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(name, BindingFlags.Public |
      BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance);
    if (fieldInfo != null)
      return fieldInfo.GetValue(obj);
    else if (propertyInfo != null)
      return propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);
    throw new IncompatibleNativeTypeException();
  }

  static public void SetMember(object obj, PathEntry member, object value)
  {
    if (member.Kind == PathEntry.PathEntryKind.Index)
      ((IList)obj)[member.Index] = value;
    else
      SetFieldOrPropertyValue(obj, member.Name, value);
  }

  static public void SetFieldOrPropertyValue(object obj, string name, object value)
  {
    FieldInfo fieldInfo = obj.GetType().GetField(name, BindingFlags.Public |
      BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance);
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(name, BindingFlags.Public |
      BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance);
    if (fieldInfo != null)
      fieldInfo.SetValue(obj, value);
    else if (propertyInfo != null)
      propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, value, null);
  }
  ...
}
```

**UPDATE:** Code at the call site:

```
object obj = ObjectConstructor.ConstructObject(encoding, objectType);
...
ObjectAccessor.SetValueAtPath(ref obj, encodingEntry.ValuePath, value);
```

@Kirk: When hovering `container` variable in the debugger after executing `SetMember` I see modified string field change from `null` to `"Sergiy"`, while when hovering `obj` and navigating to the same field it remains `null`.

Btw, the code is available here: https://github.com/rryk/opensim-omp/blob/kiara/KIARA/

**UPDATE:** I experience this wierd behavior when running on the following test: https://github.com/rryk/opensim-omp/blob/kiara/KIARA.Test/FunctionMapingConfigTest.cs

**UPDATE:** Thanks to Chris, I've realized what the problem is and re-implemented the code as following:

```
// Supports empty path in which case modifies passed obj as it's passed by reference.
static public void SetValueAtPath(ref object obj, List<PathEntry> path, object value)
{
  if (path.Count == 0)
  {
    obj = value;
    return;
  }

  // List of value types (structs) to be reassigned.
  List<KeyValuePair<object, PathEntry>> valueTypeContainers = new List<KeyValuePair<object,PathEntry>>();

  object container = obj;
  for (int i = 0; i < path.Count - 1; i++)
  {
    object newContainer = GetMember(container, path[i]);

    // Keep the trail of the value types (struct) or clear it if next container is non-value type.
    if (newContainer.GetType().IsValueType)
      valueTypeContainers.Add(new KeyValuePair<object, PathEntry>(container, path[i]));
    else
      valueTypeContainers.Clear();

    container = newContainer;
  }

  SetMember(container, path[path.Count - 1], value);

  // Reassign the value types (structs).
  for (int i = valueTypeContainers.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    object valueContainer = valueTypeContainers[i].Key;
    PathEntry pathEntry = valueTypeContainers[i].Value;
    SetMember(valueContainer, pathEntry, container);
    container = valueContainer;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us how you're calling `SetValueAtPath` (and the surrounding code)?

Comment: In addition to Simon's request, please also elaborate on what you mean by "However, according to the debugger, only container is modified and obj remains unchanged."  In what sense is container modified?

Comment: Side note: I am unable to reproduce this with any normal thought process. So something strange is going on (I suspect its your call site..).

Comment: Perhaps this is just stale data in the debugger, or you're looking when at the wrong breakpoint, or some optimizations are made if compiled for release mode. Can you instead try logging out or writing to the console the value instead of using the debugger? EDIT: Also, along the `ValuePath`, are _any_ of the members accessed value-types (`struct`) which are accessed as a property _or_ indexer? EDITx2: Since you've posted a link to the source code, what is the `objectType` and exact `encodingEntry.ValuePath` used in your test case?

Comment: I've tried printing to console - same result as in debugger. Compiling always in debug mode. Yes, there are structs on the way - see actual data types in https://github.com/rryk/opensim-omp/blob/kiara/KIARA.Test/FunctionMapingConfigTest.cs. `objectType` would be `LoginRequest`, `ValuePath` would be `["name", "first"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you have `struct` value-types in your object member path.

When you call `ObjectAccessor.GetFieldOrPropertyType` on the value-type, it returns a *copy* of the original value. Then when you eventually change a value (or dive further down the rabbit hole copying more value-type members), you're altering a copy.

I suggest you [avoid mutable structs altogether](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/14/mutating-readonly-structs.aspx). Likely if you change your types to reference-types, it will work fine.

EDIT: Given your test using types `FullName` and `LoginRequest`:

```
struct FullName 
{
    public string first;
    public string last;
}

struct LoginRequest 
{
    FullName name;
    string pwdHash;
    string start;
    string channel;
    string version;
    string platform;
    string mac;
    string[] options;
    string id0;
    string agree_to_tos;
    string read_critical;
    string viewer_digest;
}
```

And path `["name", "first"]`, it will create a copy of the `FullName` at "name", and set its "first" field value. But this copy is eventually thrown away.

It'd be the same as writing:

```
LoginRequest login = new LoginRequest();
FullName name = login.name;
name.first = "My name!";
Console.WriteLine(name.first); //My name!
Console.WriteLine(login.name.first); //null
```

EDITx2: If it's not viable to avoid nested value-types (I suspect as such considering the nature of the library), what you *can* do is set each one retrieved back. So if you determine in your loop/stack of traversing the `ValuePath` at which steps you retrieved a `struct`, then made sure to re-assign back each copy you made, it might work.

Comment: To EDITx2: see the question for the final code. I had the same idea, but I decided to keep an additional array for that.

Comment: @SergiyByelozyorov You may want to try a test when the path has a mix of types (say `class` -> `struct` -> `struct` -> `class` -> `struct` -> `struct`). I have a _suspicion_ that under such circumstances your algorithm won't work; I _think_ it will only account for the _last_ run of value-types meanwhile value-types higher up the chain that appeared before a reference-type won't be properly re-assigned and the copy-chain is broken. EDIT: I think perhaps all you need to do is avoid clearing `valueTypeContainers` when a reference-type is found. Just a guess though.

Comment: I have considered that. In fact in the case that you've presented 2nd struct will contain a reference to 2nd class in the path. Since I only modify the value in the deep-most object, I only need to reassign 4th struct (last) to the field of the 3rd struct and 3rd struct to the field of 2nd class.